# Moves "n" files, each to a specific folder with command line or bash in ubuntu

Tags: bash, ubuntu, command-line

I have multiple files in a folder. Every file has different names and have different extensions. I need a way to move each of the files into folders called Archive_1, Archive_2, Archive_n, and so on.
It doesn't matter the order of the file but I need one file per folder.

I was looking for something like sorting the files by name and based on that move the first one to Archive_1, and then the second one to Archive_2, etc. Couldn't find it.

Any help?

Comment: Can you show an example of desired input and exact output?

Comment: I have movies, let's say "12 Years a Slave.mkv" and "Akira.mp4". Both of them in the same folder. I want to move "12 Years a Slave.mkv" to a new folder named "Movie_1" and "Akira.mp4" to a new folder named "Movie_2". I need to do this on +100 files, so doing it manually its not the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all files are in *PWD*, you can execute:

```
i=0
for f in ./*; do
    new_dir=Movie_$((++i))
    mkdir -p "$new_dir"
    mv "$f" "$new_dir"
done
```

Test ( I created a script called ***sof*** with the above command ):

```
$ touch a b c
$ ./sof
$ tree
.
├── Movie_1
│   └── a
├── Movie_2
│   └── b
└── Movie_3
    └── c

3 directories, 3 files
```